# How to create Count up timer using jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, timer, count, page-refresh

**I want to create count up timer for my quiz consistent with page refresh**
I created a quiz with each one Question per page. On clicking next or previous button the form submitted to the same page. So that the timer starts again. Can someone help me to solve that issue.

Comment: Could you please provide what you did so far by adding the related code part between code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the time, when the timer started, as a cookie. Then, each time the page is loaded, check for existence of this cookie and if it exists, set the starting point of the timer to the value of this cookie.

You'll also need to reset/remove this cookie when the timer ends.